# Does Sphinx (or other third party) search engine work in my case or should I create my own?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I am creating a search function of my classifieds on my website.
Here is some of the criteria I need to meet:

- When searching for 'bmw 520' only matches where these two words come in exactly this order is returned. not matches for only 'bmw' or only '520'.
- When searching for 'bmw 330ci' results as the above will be returned, but, WITH AND WITHOUT the ci extension. There are a nr of extensions in cars as you all know (i, ci, si, fi etc).
- I want the 'minus sign' to 'exclude' all returns containing the word after the sign, ex: 'bmw -330' will return all 'bmw' results without the '330' ones. (a NOT instead of minus sign is also ok)
- all special character accents like 'é' are converted to their simple values, in this case 'e'.
- list of words to ignore completely in the search string.

Would I need Sphinx or should I write this in a php file?

What do you suggest I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Sphinx matches all of your criteria.

Answer (score 4):

I think Sphinx is pretty good match to what you want to do, but some things won't happen automatically...

- To match on two words together exactly, you either need to use the phrase match mode, or group the words in double-quotes while using the extended match mode.
- This is the tricky one - unless you specify specific exceptions, I don't think you can index 330ci as both '330 ci' and '330ci'.
- As long as you're using boolean or extended match modes, then the minus sign works as you'd like.
- 'Special' characters can be converted to standard ASCII, but this doesn't happen by default. You need to set up [your charset_table value](http://yob.id.au/2008/05/08/thinking-sphinx-and-unicode.html). This blog post is aimed at Thinking Sphinx (a Ruby plugin for Sphinx), but the setting value is just passed straight through to Sphinx.
- You can only ignore specific words on a per-query basis if you've got at least one other word in the query (that is: "-foo" will fail for Sphinx, but "foo -bar" is fine). It's worth noting that you can choose [to not index specific words](http://yob.id.au/2008/05/08/thinking-sphinx-and-unicode.html).

Comment: Sphinx can index 330ci as two and more words using min_prefix_len = 2. But it is too expensive :)